# Why HTML5 Canavas have problems with Fusion Chart elements?

Tags: html5-canvas, fusioncharts

I am trying to capture screenshot by using HTML5 canavas feature.

My web page contains few fusionchart elements.

My problem is that these **elements are not coming properly [some are entirely missing]** in captured screenshot.

In other web pages where **html table is present, Canavas is working absolutely fine**.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Export Feature of the FusionCharts library and export to PDF/PNG/JPG.

You can read more about this here: http://www.fusioncharts.com/features/export-charts-as-images-and-PDF/